# angularJS with ng-table is not loading data on returning to listing from detail page

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using angular JS with ng-tables with rails as an API. 
i successfully integrated ng-tables with server side pagination. The issue i am facing is whenever i go back list page from detail page. table data is not visible. i checked in logs and using breakpoints . i can see data but not lucky.

my controller is sampleController.js

`function sampleController($scope, $http, ngTableParams, $state, Auth) {
      $data = [];
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,
            count: 10
        }, {
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                 $http.get('sample.json', {
                        params: {
                            page: params.page()
                        }
                    })
                    .success(function(response, status) {
                        $data = response.data;
                        params.total(response.count);
                        $defer.resolve($data);
                    });
            }
        });`

and my html template is as follows

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table ng-table-responsive">
            <tr ng-repeat="data in $data.tasks">
                <td data-title="'Title'">
                    {{data.title}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

also i referred [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694161/angularjs-ng-table-is-not-showing-data-on-returning-to-listing) . but i couldn't able to fix it.

I appreciate your time and input. Hoping for solution from you guys.

Comment: i figured out the issue after debugging for 1 hour . this problem was in entire project. then i removed 
//= require turbolinks from application.js and uninstalled gem . 
worked like a charm.